# .htaccess - hidding .php and forcing trailing slash not working

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to hide `.php` extension from my website while forcing trailing slash, I've been searching for the last few days with no success.

The site is running in a XAMPP server currently.

Here's the `.htaccess` file:

```
Options -Indexes -Multiviews +FollowSymlinks

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

#removing .php extension
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ /[^?\s]+\.php
RewriteRule (.*)\.php$ /$1/ [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(.+)/$
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%1.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ $1.php [L]

#forcing trailing slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule .*[^/]$ $0/ [L,R=301]

ErrorDocument 404 http://localhost/404/
```

**These links work:**

`localhost/about-us` redirects to `localhost/about-us/` which is correct but when I try to access `localhost/about-us.php`, it redirects to `localhost/about-us/` instead of `localhost/about-us/`. (sorry can't post links)

How can this be fixed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just seem to have accidentally used an absolute path. Just remove the slash at the beginning of `/$1/` like your other rules to make it work properly.

```
#removing .php extension
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ /[^?\s]+\.php
RewriteRule (.*)\.php$ $1/ [L,R=301]
```